# Dynamically Adding Items To a WPF List View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I am trying to programatically add items to a ListView in WPF.  I have done a lot of reading (including some questions here) and thought I was doing it correctly but the items aren't showing up.  As I understand it I create the ListViewe and bind it to a data source, in this case an ObservableCollection.  I have verified the ObservableCollection is getting items added to it, but they aren't getting displayed on the ListView.  If it matters, the ListView is already instantiated by the time I run the LINQ query and attempt to add items to it.

Here is the XAML that defines the list view:

```
<TabPanel Name="ResultsTab" Height="200" Width ="500" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TabItem Name="Default_Tab" Header="Default">
            <ListView Name="DefaultListView" ItemsSource="Binding FCPortCollection">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="DefaultGridView">
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="FC Port" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FCPort}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="WWPN" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=WWPN}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="FCID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FCID}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="SwitchName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SwitchName}">
                        </GridViewColumn>                 
                    </GridView>   
                </ListView.View>     
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
```

And here is the code that is supposed to load it.

```
public class PortResult
{
    public string SwitchName;
    public string FCPort;
    public string FCID;
    public string WWPN;

    public PortResult(string name, FCPort port)
    {
        SwitchName = name;
        FCPort = String.Format("fc{0}/{1}", port.SlotNum, port.PortNum);
        WWPN = port.WWPNList[0].WWPNValue;
        FCID = port.WWPNList[0].FCIDValue;

    }
}

ObservableCollection<PortResult> FCPortCollection = new ObservableCollection<PortResult>();

// results is an IEnumerable collection of FCPort result from a LINQ query that has been turned into a Dictionary
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<FCPort>> resultspair in results)
      {
            foreach (FCPort port in resultspair.Value)
            {    
                // create a new PortResult and add it to the ObservableCollection
                PortResult pr = new PortResult(resultspair.Key, port);
                FCPortCollection.Add(pr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Know [how to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: You're welcome, those basics are important :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in the code you posted:

1. The binding syntax for your `ItemsSource` is missing the {} braces - it needs to be `ItemsSource="{Binding FCPortCollection}"`
2. You can only bind to properties, however you only expose fields in your `PortResult` class. Change those fields to be properties.

Also make sure the DataContext of the `ListView` is set to the object which contains the `FCPortCollection`. Also make sure the collection is a property of the object and not a field (same reason as point 2. above).

Comment: I fixed the ItemsSource issue and changed the the PortResult Class to have public properties backed by private fields.  I also added this:     DefaultListView.DataContext = FCPortCollection; to the code.  FCPortCollection is a class variable of type ObserveableCollection for the form that contains the ListView  Stll no joy.

Comment: @DavidGreen: If you set the DataContext of the ListView directly to the collection then you need to use `ItemsSource={Binding}` (no path specified). The binding is always relative to the data context. If if you say `{Binding Foo}` then the binding engine will look for a property called `Foo` in the data context object.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I fixed some issues and the DataContext is now showing a list of items, as is the ItemsSource in the debugger WatchWindow. However, the ListView is still not displaying the items.  I verified that the names of the properties in the PortResult Class are the same names as the bindings for the GridViewColumns

Comment: Oh is it an issue that I am doing all of this after InitializeComponent() is called for the window that contains the ListView?  Most of the examples I see have all this in the constructor for the form that contains the ListView, then InitializeComponent() is called.  Eventually I want to be able to add tabs to the TabCollection with other listviews that have different search results

Comment: thanks for all the help.  After some more work in the debugger, I got rid of the Tab Control. Now the list works and I can see it.  I'd like to figure out why I can't see the list inside the tab control.  My idea is to be able to run different queries on the data with each one in its own tab.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```xml
ItemsSource="Binding FCPortCollection"
```

Is not a binding, you forgot the braces `{}` and hence assigned a `char[]` as `ItemsSource` instead.